# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification not work when i use custom textField.inputView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

In my program I create a custom view on xib and want use this view like `textField.inputView`. When `KeyboardWillShow` i want change inputView frame, but `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` do not work when i tap on this textField. How i can change `textField.inputView` or to force work `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 0);
    self.actionView = [[ActionView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];            
    self.actionView.delegate = self; 
    self.currencyTextField.inputView = self.actionView;
    [self layout]; 
} 
- (void)addObserver{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSDictionary* keyboardUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[keyboardUserInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.actionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.width, keyboardSize.height);
    [self.currencyTextField reloadInputViews];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-zero height

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 100);
```

Also don't forget to call

```
[self addObserver];
```

end of `viewDidLoad`